# Membership.lastactivitydate

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-membership

i have this code block in page_load of my site master

```
 MembershipUser msu = Membership.GetUser(Page.User.Identity.Name);
 msu.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;
 Membership.UpdateUser(msu);
```

but when i got users last activity time the date time is wrong

i did test it in 06/23/2015 about 10:25 PM but i got this times:

- 6/27/2015 2:16:08 AM !!!!!
- 6/30/2015 11:14:51 AM !!!!!!
- 6/30/2016 9:14:51 PM !!!!!!!!! 2016?????!!!!!!
- 6/27/2015 6:46:08 AM !!!!!!!!!
- 7/1/2015 11:14:51 PM

what is my fault???

please help me

Comment: what membership provider are you using?

Comment: <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>